# EV3 force sensor - how to download the block to EV3?

Tags: ev3, ev3-g

I'm a twelfth grade student and I'm studying mechatronics and this is the first time someone from my school has used a force sensor so my teachers do not know how to help me. Can you please tell me: how can I download the force sensor block to EV3?

Answer (score 3):

There is no force sensor in either the commercial or education version of the EV3 set, just the touch sensor for which there are standard blocks.

So I'm going to assume this is a sensor from an an external party. You need a file with extension .ev3b that can be imported in the mindstorms lab by clicking 'Tools' in the menu and then 'import block' which will open a dialog where you can browse for the file, and import the blocks in it.

[image]

[image]

Now to obtain that .ev3b file, you need to know from which vendor it was bought. Likely the file can be downloaded from their website. We could help you further if you could specify either the vendor or post a picture of the sensor.

Comment: +1, but I'm kind of assuming this "sensor" is made with the existing parts or electronics from the original set (ie the large motor, but it can't accurately detect "force"). Based on the context of the question, I doubt the user can get his hands on a custom 3rd-party snesor, especially since it's apparently a school project. or maybe im wrong

Comment: I think it actually more likely for a school teacher to buy a force sensor than a hobbyist. Can be used to teach various scientific principles in a STEM course...